# typeof is an operator and a function

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript `typeof` is an operator and a function.  Is it better used as an operator or a function?  Why?

Comment: A bit off topic: Actually, it's rare that I use `typeof` these days. AFAIK, `typeof` is slower than a direct check, as it needs to check for many different types in order to return a string. Therefore, I always check for the constructor instead (if possible), like, `if (("hello").constructor == String) {...}`

Comment: @Sune Rasmussen - From the limited profiling I just did, the constructor check in Firefox 3.6 is twice as slow as `typeof`. I had a `var func = function(){};` and then I did both a `typeof func != "function"` check as well as a `func.constructor != Function` check. The former was twice as fast.

Comment: If you use jQuery the execution time of `typeof` is negligible.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

`typeof` is an operator. You can easily check it using:

```
typeof(typeof)
```

Were `typeof` a function, this expression would return `'function'` string, but it results in a syntax error:

```
js> typeof(typeof);
typein:8: SyntaxError: syntax error:
typein:8: typeof(typeof);
typein:8: .............^
```

so, `typeof` cannot be a function. Probably parenthesis-notation `typeof(foo)` made you think `typeof` is a function, but syntactically, those parenthesis are not *function call* - they are those used for grouping, just like `(2 + 3) *2`. In fact, you can add any number of them you want:

```
typeof(((((foo))))); // is equal to typeof foo;
```

Comment: Note this is true for other operators - `[] instanceof(Object)`.

Comment: Same for many other keywords. `if(foo)` doesn't make `if` a function, same for `return(bar);` and `while(test)`.

Answer (score 5):

I think you pick which you want based on clarity, as a habit I usually use it as an operator in the following way because it's pretty clear, at least IMO:

```
if(typeof thing === "string") { 
  alert("this is a string");
}

if(typeof thing === "function") {
  alert("this is a function");
}
```

This is opposed to this format:

```
if(typeof(thing) === "string") { 
  alert("this is a string");
}
```

Which to me, makes it slightly slower to read.  If you do `typeof(thing)` it's the same thing, so whatever floats your boat.  [You can get a full read and what strings to expect from types here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator).

Comment: So there is no understood better way?  Does there exist a JavaScript style guide?

Comment: @hekevintran - There's not a specific standards guide for everyone, you can find a major framework that's mature and follow it's styling perhaps, something like jQuery or Prototype...but again these are the styles of that team, so it's not necessarily the "standard".

Comment: bloody hell, I was unaware of being able to specify sans "()"'s.

Comment: Shouldn't this answer explicitly say "`typeof` is always an operator" or "`typeof` is not a function"?  `I usually use it as an operator` -- it's **always** an operator, no?  I mean, we don't have a choice, do we?

Comment: @MattFenwick You don't have a choice. It's an operator, not a function. People commonly think it's a function because other people put parens around the argument.