# How to get associative array as output from jQuery.map?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQuery [map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function to get an array of inputs' values:

```
var inputs = $("[id^='field']");
var values = inputs.map(function () { 
                             return $(this).val(); 
                        }).get();
```

I would like to get an associative array of [id, value]:

```
{
   id1: value1, 
   id2: value2
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`.map()` returns an array, so if you want an object with id values as the keys, then you can do it like this:

```
function getFieldValues() {
    var values = {};
    $("[id^='field']").each(function() {
        values[this.id] = this.value;
    });
    return values;
}
```

Comment: Curious to know why you're using `return(values)`. It makes it look like a function.

Comment: I see. The downside that I see is that type of syntax can confuse beginners. A common point of confusion is `typeof x` vs `typeof(x)`.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797517/typeof-is-an-operator-and-a-function). Don't forget who your audience is.

Comment: The audience is StackOverflow. I didn't meant to imply that you shouldn't personally use it. I just meant that the `()` presents an ambiguity for those who don't realize that `return` is a statement, and never a function, and that after a statement, it's just a plain old group. The `typeof` question I linked is a good example. Up to you, but I think it would at least help if there was a space when you use it. `return (values)` Your call. ;)

Comment: Note: associative arrays and objects are the same thing in JS.

Answer (score 1):

```
var values = inputs.map(function () { 
                             var obj = {};
                             obj[ this.id ] = $(this).val(); 
                             return obj;
                        }).get();
```

If they're not `select` or `radio` inputs, use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`.

Or if you just wanted an object, use `.each`.

```
var obj = {};
inputs.each(function () { 
                             obj[ this.id ] = $(this).val(); 
                        });
```

---

If you did want an array of objects, and if your inputs have their `name` property, you could also use `serializeArray`.

```
var values = inputs.serializeArray();
```

Comment: This will create an array of objects. I assume he just wants to get an object.

Comment: @FelixKling: I think you're right. I'll update unless someone else beats me to it. ;)

Comment: @RightSaidFred: Ya, Felix is right, I want an object, not an array of objects.

Comment: excellent, i had to port over an underscore _.map to $.map and for some reason in _.map, wrapping the 'key' and 'value like this: [ question.name, {'value': question.value, 'config': question.config} ] doesn't translate verbatum to $.